# Filter table by tags provided - active record

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the below tables

1. User
2. Article
3. Tags (1 to many)

Tags can be applied for both the user and articles . (user tags are tags to be blacklisted - i.e do not show articles tagged with user submitted tags). As such they have the below columns

1. id
2. taggable_type ('article' or 'user')
3. title  (string)
4. taggable id (the relevant article id or the userid)

When the user performs a get request , i would like to have activerecord filter out all articles with the provided user blacklisted tags.

i perform the below operation to get an array of user blacklisted tags

```
if user != nil
  user_tags = user.tags
  blacklisted_tags = []
  user_tags.each do |user|
    blacklisted_tags.push(user.title)
  end
  puts "\n \n \n user tags - #{blacklisted_tags} \n \n \n"
end

blacklisted_tags = ['foo','bar']
```

I cant seem to get activerecord to properly filter out any article tagged with any of the blacklisted_tags.

this is what i've done so far

```
negations[:tags] = "tags.title not in #{blacklisted_tags}"

@articles = Article.order(followed).left_outer_joins(:tags).where.not(negations)
```

i get the below sql error -

```
(Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'articles.taggable_id' in 'where clause': SELECT  `articles`.* FROM `articles` LEFT OUTER JOIN `tags` ON `tags`.`taggable_id` = `articles`.`id` AND `tags`.`taggable_type` = 'article' WHERE (`articles`.`taggable_id` != 'tags.title not in [\"foo\", \"bar\"]')
```

Where is rails getting the 'articles.taggable_id' from?

Is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try:

```
@articles = Article.joins(:tags).where.not(tags: { title: blacklisted_tags})
```

Comment: then try negative the condition